# Are the following relations reflexive/irreflexive/neither? Symmetric/asymmetric/neither? Transitive/intransitive/neither?

Tags: logic, modal-logic

Are the following relations reflexive/irreflexive/neither? Symmetric/asymmetric/neither? Transitive/intransitive/neither?

1) x is a biological father of y

2) x is between point a and y. (Here, let the domain D = {x | x is a geometrical point in 3-dimensional space}. 'a' names some arbitrary fixed geometrical point. Also, let the between-ness relation mean that x lies on a straight line between a and y).

3) x formally implies y.

4) x and y are formally consistent.

5) x isn't identical to y.

Comment: What do you think? What progress have you made so far?

Comment: Number one I have irreflexive , asymmetric and intransitive.

Comment: 2) im confused with , 3) I believe is reflexive, symmetric, transitive. I stopped at this point because im unsure if I'm doing it correctly or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We begin by recalling the basic definitions needed to settle the questions:

> **Definitions.**
>
> R is *reflexive*       =<sub>def</sub>   ∀<sub>w</sub> : wRw;
>   R is *symmetric*    =<sub>def</sub>   ∀<sub>w, v</sub> : (wRv → vRw);
>   R is *transitive*      =<sub>def</sub>   ∀<sub>w, v, u</sub> : (wRv ∧ vRu) → wRu.

Now we identify the relations in questions (1–5), ignoring the other details:

> **Question 1.** R(x,y) ≡ BiologicalFatherOf(x, y).

You're right about R being *irreflexive* and *asymmetric*, because no person is a biological father of himself and no person is a biological father of his father. But R is also *intransitive*, because the biological father of your biological father is not your biological father!

> **Question 2.** R(x, y) ≡ [x ∈ (a..y)], where a is fixed and (x..y) is the straight line from x to y inclusive.

Is R reflexive, i.e., is R(x,x) true? R(x,x) is true iff x ∈ (a..x), i.e., iff x is on the straight line from a to x inclusive (Sorry for the unorthodox notation; I hope its use is justified here). Because of the inclusiveness, x is indeed on that line, so R is *reflexive*.

To check for symmetry, assume R(x,y) and ask is R(y,x) true? R(x,y) implies that x ∈ (a..y), i.e., x is on the straight line from a to y. R(y,x) says that y ∈ (a..x), i.e., that y is on the straight line from a to x. R is not symmetric, because the line from a to y might be longer from the line from a to x.

To check for transitivity, assume R(x,y) and R(y,z) and ask is R(x,z) true? R(x,y) means that x is on the straight line between a and y, and R(y,z) means that y is on the straight line from a to z, so the line from a to z is an extension of the line from a to y. It's given that x is between a and y, and since the line from a to z extends the line from a to y, x must also be between a and z! So R is *transitive*.
<sub>† Thanks to [Lucas](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/users/4316/lucas) for directing me toward the right interpretation of the relation.</sub>

> **Question 3.** R(x, y) ≡ (x → y).

You're right about reflexivity and transitivity, but wrong about symmetry. R is *reflexive* because every statement x materially implies itself. R can be seen to be *transitive* by two applications of modus ponens or detachment. R is certainly not symmetric, otherwise material implication collapses to equivalence.

> **Question 4.** R(x, y) ≡ Consistent(x, y).

R is *reflexive*, because any statement is consistent with itself (I'm not sure about contradictions; should we exclude them or say that two contradictions are somehow consistent?). R is *symmetric*, because if x is consistent with y, then y is consistent with x. R is not *transitive*, because while x may be consistent with y, x may be inconsistent with some z consistent with y. That is because for x and y to be consistent, (x ∧ y) has to be *satisfiable*, which may be true for *different* reasons for (x and y) and (y and z), so (x and z) might still turn out to be unsatisfiable.

> **Question 5.** R(x, y) ≡ (x != y).

R is *irreflexive*, because every x is indeed identical to itself. R is *symmetric* because if x isn't identical to y, then y is also not identical to x. Lastly, R is not transitive, because while (x and y) and (y and z) might be distinct, it doesn't imply that (x and z) are distinct, i.e., (x = z) is possible.

Comment: You've misread the definition of 2, should be "x is between a and y" not "a is between x and y"